# Sql query needs creative solution

Tags: mysql

I have data that looks like this

```
object_id type

1         ISSN

1         ISBN

2         ISSN

2         ISSN

3         ISSN

3         KSBN

3         KSBN

4         ISSN

4         ISBN
```

I need to find all the data that has both an ISSN and ISBN in the same query.

The solution I found was using this code

```
select * 
from table
where OBJECT_ID in 
(
    SELECT K.OBJECT_ID
    FROM tableK
    WHERE K.`TYPE` IN ('ISSN', 'ISBN') 
    GROUP BY K.OBJECT_ID
    HAVING count(distinct K.TYPE) = 2
)
```

However it takes a long time to run since the data set is large. Is there an option for not using a nested query.

When I put the objectID's directly it runs almost instantly

```
select * 
from table
where OBJECT_ID in 
(
    1,4
)
```

it runs much faster because it's not executing the select many times. however when I try to save the output as a variable it crashes because it returns more than one row.

Is there any type of join that can be done on the smaller data set because doing a reflexive join on the entire table takes more than 10 minutes.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table as t1
  INNER JOIN table as t2 
  ON t1.object_id = t2.object_id 
  AND t2.type = "ISSN"
WHERE t1.type = "ISBN"
```

Comment: I need to find all the data, this will condense it to show only one record from the set that it found. i.e. if the Object_id is used twice it should show it twice.

Comment: There I updated the selected fields. Anyway, with this you are fetching all the records where type is ISBN and that have a join with ISSN. Isn't this what you want?